# Delaunay triangulation in (n>3) dimensions

Tags: java, r

I have 10-dimensional data and was wondering if there is existing R or java code that can Delaunay triangulate it.  I have used ashape3d in R but it appears (name implied) to only work in 3D.

Comment: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html might have a link for you somewhere.

Comment: Thank you kindly.  Is that not more for 2D?  I'm currently considering CGAL (https://www.cgal.org/) and Qhull (http://www.qhull.org/).  I stumbled across them after I posted the question.  Thanks,

Comment: I think Triangle is 2D. Be sure to post your solution as an answer when you decide what to use. I know I'd be interested.

Comment: Will do.  Hopefully by tomorrow.  Thanks,

Comment: The `geometry` package wraps Qhull.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use the algorithm outlined in the paper ``Incremental Construction of the Delaunay Triangulation and the Delaunay Graph in Medium Dimension'', Jean-Daniel Boissonnat, Olivier Devillers and Samuel Hornus, *ACM Symposium on Computational Geometry (SCG)*, 2009.  It is based on CGAL.  [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) is another possibility.